# Telerik grid for ASP.NET MVC2 (VS2008)

Tags: telerik-mvc

Does Telerik grid for ASP.NET MVC2 (VS2008) exist? If so, please, provide the link to trial version.

We need such a grid with toolbar and other standard options.

Thank you in advance.

Goran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik no longer provides MVC2/VS2008 wrappers. The current product Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC supports MVC3+ and VS2010+ only.